# how to make multiple selects with conditional aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

EDITED
The query below gives me the avg of all type of coverage for 2019 given certain conditions, (note that the triplet: number, name and coverage make an element in the first select and the sum of those that are below 0 are excluded; I need to get the average of the price of those filtered elements for each year grouped by coverage)

```
 Select ROUND(AVG(Amount), 2) average_2019, coverage, count(*) from
   (SELECT number, name, SUM(price) Amount, coverage, count(*) FROM myTable
where (To_date("Activity Date", 'mm-dd-yyyy') between TO_DATE('01/01/2019','mm/dd/yyyy') and TO_DATE('01/01/2019','mm/dd/yyyy'))
group by number, name, coverage having SUM(price)>0)
group by coverage;
```

I want to display also the average for other years, like both 2018 and 2019 but I havent found a way to do this.

output gives 3 columns:

### coverages | average2019 | count

but I want 5 columns including 2018 year:

### coverages | average2019 | count | average2018 | count

I tried using 'case when' to filter for year but then I wont be able to select by the triplets(name, number, coverage), and I need the average of those. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: What's your requirement?

Comment: You still haven't provided sample data and matching actual/expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a table like this:

```
create table myTable (numero number
                      , name varchar2(50)
                      , price number
                      , coverage number
                      , activity_date date);
```

And inserted some data:

```
insert into myTable values (1, 'name1', 20, 50, to_date('02.10.2018','dd.mm.yyyy'));
insert into myTable values (2, 'name2', 10, 50, to_date('05.10.2018','dd.mm.yyyy'));
insert into myTable values (3, 'name3', 40, 50, to_date('02.10.2019','dd.mm.yyyy'));
insert into myTable values (4, 'name3', 60, 50, to_date('10.10.2019','dd.mm.yyyy'));
```

This is the sub-query:

```
SELECT numero
       , name
       , SUM(price) Amount
       , coverage
       , count(*) 
       , max(extract(year from activity_date)) year
FROM myTable
where (activity_date between TO_DATE('02.10.2018','dd.mm.yyyy') 
      and TO_DATE('20.10.2019','dd.mm.yyyy'))
group by numero
         , name
         , coverage having SUM(price) > 0;
```

And the query with the sub-query:

```
SELECT coverage as coverages,
       round(avg(case when year = 2018 then Amount end), 2) average2018,
       count( case when year = 2018 then Amount end) count_2018,
       round(avg(case when year = 2019 then Amount end), 2) average2019,
       count( case when year = 2019 then Amount end) count_2019
FROM
(SELECT numero
        , name
        , SUM(price) Amount
        , coverage
        , count(*) 
        , max(extract(year from activity_date)) year
FROM myTable
where (activity_date between TO_DATE('02.10.2018','dd.mm.yyyy') 
      and TO_DATE('20.10.2019','dd.mm.yyyy'))
group by numero
         , name
         , coverage having SUM(price) > 0)
group by coverage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Does including `year` in the subquery do what you want?

```
Select typeItem, count(*), 
       round(avg(case when year = 2018 then price end), 2) avg_2018,
       round(avg(case when year = 2019 then price end), 2) average_2019
from (select number, name, typeItem, year, sum(price) as Amount, count(*)  as cnt             
      from myTable
      where status = 'active' 
      group by number, name, typeItem, year
      having SUM(price) > 0
     ) t
group by typeItem;
```

I am a little unclear on what you want the `count()` to count in the outer query, so that value may not be what you want.

Comment: no, beacuase I need to group by number, name, typeItem which make a feature and count those features